# How to show different images depending on the geolocalization in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, show

```js
function getLocation()
    { if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(doRequest);
    }
}
function getCountry(addrComponents){
    for (var i = 0; i < addrComponents.length; i++){
        if (addrComponents[i].types[0] == "country") {
        return addrComponents[i].short_name;
    }
}
    return false;
}

function doRequest(position) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&sensor=false', true);

xhr.onload = function (){

        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (data.results.length > 0) {
            console.log(getCountry(data.results[0].address_components));
        } };

        xhr.send();
    }


        window.onload = getLocation();
```

Comment: Please consider adding a little more context to introduce your question.

Comment: Please retag as @javascript.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in this.